# layout background scaling, using xml file as background

Tags: android, android-layout

The app I am developing have a background image which I would like to have scaling to the different device sizes, most important it should fit the width. The background fades into black, so I can have a permanent black background on the main view and that looks just fine.

I have made a background.xml file, and at the moment I have only the xlarge background image of 800x1280 px graphic in the res folder. When I run my app on a AVD with the settings of the Samsung Galaxy S3 the background width do not fill the entire screen, yet the rest of the controls scales just fine to the screen.

This is the start of my view:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/MainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

My background.xml looks like this:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:src="@drawable/mainappbg" 
android:gravity="top|left" android:filter="true" android:dither="true" />
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

I have tried this, there is an image inserted as background but only the TasksButton and ServiceRapportButton are visible, the rest of the content disapears.

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/MainScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:background="#000000" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:src="@drawable/mainappbg"/>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/lineLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="85dp">
   <Button android:id="@+id/TasksButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:background="@drawable/opgaver" android:onClick="TasksClickHandler" android:textSize="12sp"/>
   <Button android:id="@+id/ServiceRapportButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginRight="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="40dp" android:background="@drawable/rapport" android:onClick="ServiceRapportClickHandler" android:textSize="12sp"/>       
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
      <Button android:id="@+id/LineButton" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/lines" android:onClick="LineClickHandler" android:textSize="12dp"/>        
      <Button android:id="@+id/ServiceButton" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/service" android:textSize="12dp" android:onClick="ServiceClickHandler"></Button>
      <Button android:id="@+id/NavigationButton" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/navigate" android:textSize="12dp" android:onClick="NavigateClickHandler"></Button>         
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit, added screenshot, I want to place a background behind these controls:
[image: Screenshot of app screen]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only purpose of `LinearLayout` (`@id/lineLayout1`) is to serve as bg container, then replace it with `ImageView` set [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) to match scaling results you want to achieve.

**EDIT**

Wrap it in RelativeLayout layout and put ImageView as BG container:

```
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainScrollView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:background="#000000" 
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:fillViewport="true">

   <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:src="@drawable/beta_bg_drawable"/>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:background="#5500ff00" 
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The LinearLayout serves as a container for the rest of the layouts and controls of the view. Like TableLayouts and RelativeLayouts with buttons and textviews.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from wrapping your LinearLayout into RelativeLayout, with ImageView serving as BG container and LinearLayout overlapping it with transparency.

Comment: So putting a RelativeLayout around the LinearLayout and have the ImageView inside that you mean?

Comment: The content of LinearLayout is not showing when both the ImageView and the LinearLayout is children of a RelativeLayout, what am I missing?

Comment: See edited answer with working layout. You need to feed ImageView with your drawable

Comment: Edited my question with what I tried, but only some of the content of view is now shown.

Comment: Your updated layout is bit broken (width 0dp etc). Show the picture so we could see how it should look finally?

Comment: I have figured out that the RelativeLayout puts all the other layout containers after ImageView to the right of ImageView, and therefore outside the viewport for some reason. Atleast thats what Eclipse layout editor says.

Comment: No, it does not. By default each elements are placed at 0x0 overlapping each other. In general I am not fully understand how your layout should finally look like. I believe that i.e. TableLayout is pointless and can be replaed with LinearLayout in case of one row etc. If you describe how it should look, then we could help. I'd also not use onClick from XML

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my post. Everything looks fine, and scales fine, but I want to place a background behind this layout.

Comment: when you wrap it all in relative layout and put ImageView as 1st child and then rest of your layout next, then ImageView will be on "bottom".

Comment: On bottom? do not know what you mean about that. If I put ImageView in, like my edited post, then the background scales but only the button with text "Opgaver" in the top right corner is visible.

Comment: Bottom in terms of depth (in 3d :). Or in "back" if you prefer in 2d

Comment: Well, that is also how I understood it, but all the content of the child elements of the LinearLayout are gone, except for the "Opgaver" and "Rapport" buttons in the first RelativeLayout child.

Comment: blind guess - remove margins from these buttons and they shall appear in top left corner. then reposition them again. is the layout in your question recent one? if not - update

Comment: It is recent.  There is not any margin on the content which is not shown. There is margin on "Opgaver" but that is the only content which is actually shown.

Comment: This is what I find annoying working with Eclipse. I have now undoed it all, saved, closed Eclipse and put it all in again. And now the image is there, it scales and all the controls loads as they should!! I have some problems with the background image not looking good, but that has somthing to do with my image.

Comment: Good it works. Your layout is buggy a bit still - your lineLayout1 (should be rather orientation=vertical). Your tableLayot1 childs should not be `0dp` width but rather `wrap_content`. I'd replace that TableLayout with horizontal LinearLayout and change all its buttons' width to fill_parent and set layout_weight to 1

Comment: I will look into that, but I had some problems with wrap_content messing up the scaling on the button, so it did not stick to the height/width ratio.